# Localization at a monic polynomial: Horrocks' theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

A theorem of Horrocks states that if $P$ is a projective $R[x]$-module ($R$ a local ring) such that $P_S$ is a free $R[x]_S$-module (where $S\subset R[x]$ is the set of all monic polynomials in $R[x]$), then $P$ is also $R[x]$-free.

My question is if this is also true if $P_f$ is a free $R[x]_f$-module for some $f\in S$.

I apreciate every answer, even though I am afraid the question is trivial.

Comment: @ YACP But i just find it as a consequence of his actual theorem. i have never seen it proven...

Comment: I don't have it with me, but I would suggest looking in TY Lam's exposition on the Serre Problem. He has a whole chapter on Horrock's theorem.

Comment: Also, it's on Springer Link if your university has that available to you.

Comment: @YACP first I was wondering if this is true now I ask myself why this is true...

Comment: @Alex Youcis I also thought of that but I can't find it in there. In Lam's "Serres problem on projective modules" it is though shown that Horrocks theorem follows (for commutative local rings) if $P_f$ is $R[x]_f$ free. But I am interested in the other direction...

Comment: @Heffalump You could email Lam if no one answers. If I see him and he's not busy, I might ask him. I've been wanting to read his book anyways.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I would be more than honored. I have been studying his book for quite a long time now and I can really recommend it! thanks!

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks a lot! I don't have his first book but I will look that up.

Comment: @YACP oops, I didn't do that on porpuse. I was confused by his initials. By the way, I could solve my question now and it was really trivial so I am sorry for my post..

Comment: @YACP my question was, why we now if $P_f$ is $R[x]_f$ free, that $P_S$ is $R[x]_S$ free. And this is, as I feared, trivial. But you are right, my question kind of  changed during that conversation. I was confused, not only with your names. sorry!

Comment: Since you've managed to sort it out, you are encouraged to answer your own question. It can be especially useful for future visitors if you indicate where you were stuck, and how you resolved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well from his comments, the OP wants to know if one can replace in Horrocks' theorem "$P_S$ is a free $R[x]_S$-module (where $S\subset R[x]$ is the set of all monic polynomials in $R[x]$)" with "$P_f$ is a free $R[x]_f$-module for some $f\in S$". Of course we can as long as the first assertion follows from the second.

In general, if $M$ is an $R$-module, $S\subset R$ a multiplicative system, $f\in S$, and $M_f$ is $R_f$-free, then $M_S$ is $R_S$-free. This is trivial, since $M_S=R_S\otimes_{R_f}M_f$.